# How to revert strokes in Illustrator and make them uniform?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I messed up tried to connect some lines in control y.

When I came back I saw things totally messed up. there are a lot of thick and thin lines and some have circles on them.

Does someone know how to make them equal and remove the circles?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there is *always* `Edit > Undo` and repeat that as often as necessary.

Second...

- Select All
- In the **Appearance Panel** menu, choose `Clear Appearance`.
- Set a stroke weight in the **Stroke Panel**.

Doing these steps should create uniform strokes.

Comment: thank you so much! :)